# How is something level trigger vs edge triggered?

Tags: digital-logic

I understand what they both are, but how exactly is something "made" to be edge triggered? I understand some computer architecture concepts, and while I understand individual components (gates/flip flops/etc...) I don't understand what makes something rising edge/falling edge triggered or level triggered for example?

Im more or less looking for a "Physical" reason that determines why one vs the other.

Comment: Look at master-slave d-flipflop configuration.

Comment: @Transistor I think OP wants the physical explanation of how the transistors inside a device act when they are edge vs level triggered?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen that is correct that is what I was looking for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhpW4d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The input of the AND gate is either L,H or H,L. Never L,L or H,H. So, the output is always L. Right?

**WRONG!**

- **Every gate has a propagation delay. A few nanoseconds.**

What happens is the following.

- Input is L. The AND sees H,L. The output is L.
- Input has a L→H transition. The inverter has a delay. The AND sees H,H. The output is H.
- The inverter finally propagated the H on its input. The AND sees L,H. The Output is L.
- Input has a H→L transition. The inverter has a delay. The AND sees L,L. The output is L.
- The inverter finally propagated the L on its input. The AND sees H,L. The Output is L.

So, this circuit is an edge-detector for the L→H transition. It creates a few nanosecond H pulse during that transition.

Answer (score 1):

In SOC systems which I have seen they work a bit different from what most people expect: They do NOT use the interrupt signal rising/falling edge immediately.

Completely a-synchronous interrupts first need to be synchronized. This is not needed with most internal generated interrupts as they are often generated by a circuit which is already running at the CPU clock.

Then the signal is delayed by one-clock cycle which give you the 'previous' state. Next a logic circuit checks if the current value differs from the previous one. If so you had an edge.

- If the old state was low and the current state is high you have a rising edge.
- If the old state was high and the current state is low you have a falling edge.

Here is some Verilog code:

```
module irq_edge (
   input  sys_clk,
   input  sys_reset_n,
   input  async_irqA,   // A-synchronous  interrupt
   input  sync_irqB,    // synchronous  interrupt

   // Outputs
   // Beware : high for only one clock cycle
   output rising_edge_A,
   output rising_edge_B,
   output falling_edge_A,
   output falling_edge_B
   );

reg meta_syncA,safe_syncA;

reg prev_irqA,prev_irqB;

   always @(posedge sys_clk or negedge sys_reset_n)
   begin
      if (!sys_reset_n)
      begin
         meta_syncA <= 1'b0;
         safe_syncA <= 1'b0;
         prev_irqA  <= 1'b0;
         prev_irqB  <= 1'b0;         
      end
      else
      begin
         // Sychronise async_irqA to system clock
         meta_syncA <= async_irqA;
         safe_syncA <= meta_syncA;

         // Delay for edge detection
         prev_irqA  <= safe_syncA;
         prev_irqB  <= sync_irqB;
      end
   end

   // Compare old and current value of signals
   assign rising_edge_A  = ~prev_irqA &  safe_syncA; // was low now high
   assign rising_edge_B  = ~prev_irqB &  sync_irqB;  // was low now 
   assign falling_edge_A =  prev_irqA & ~safe_syncA; // was high now low
   assign falling_edge_B =  prev_irqB & ~sync_irqB;  // was high now low

endmodule
```

And here is a waveform:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to create an edge-sensitive flip flop is to combine two level-sensitive latches which are sensitive to opposite states of the clock.

To create a rising edge triggered flip flop, you would first have a latch which is transparent when the clock is low. The output of that latch would go to the input of a latch which is transparent when the clock is high.